# Filtering the excel data in c#.always getting 1 rows but excel filters correctly

Tags: c#, excel

While filtering first time rows.count working correctly(count =3 including header).But Next time always getting 1 only.But excel filters working perfectly.

[image]

```
List<string> mylist = new List<string> {"Sankar","raja" };
            foreach (var item in mylist)
            {
            var PcInfoFile = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            PcInfoFile.Visible = true;
            PcInfoWorkbook = PcInfoFile.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\filter.xlsx");

            var  worksheet = PcInfoWorkbook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            worksheet.AutoFilterMode = false;

            var range = worksheet.UsedRange;
            range.AutoFilter(1, item, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlFilterValues, Type.Missing, true);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range filteredRange = range.SpecialCells(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSpecialCellsValue.xlTextValues);

            int nFilterCount = filteredRange.Rows.Count;
            }
```

Comment: You may want to check whether the cell with the name "raja" has spaces after the word "raja". You can do this by selecting the cell, pressing F2, and moving to the end of the text to see if there are spaces at the end. If so, deleting them may resolve the issue.

Comment: Aside from checking for extra spaces in the "raja" cell, you may want to avoid opening the workbook and setting the worksheet variable inside the `foreach` loop. You can do this by relocating the first 3 lines of the `foreach` body (where you create the `Application` and `Workbook` objects) and the line where you set the `worksheet` variable. These lines can go above the `foreach` loop so that they are only executed once. You may then want to close the workbook some time after the loop.